# Asegurar que un string solo tenga letras

Tags: php, preg-match

Estoy haciendo una verificacion de un formulario y tengo esta validación para que en un input de tipo text el usuario solo introduzca letras.

```
 if (empty(trim($nombre)) || !is_string($nombre) || preg_match("/[0-9]/",$nombre)){
                $nombre_validado=false;
                $errores='Nombre no válido';
                echo "Nombre no valido";
            }else{
                $nombre_validado=true;
                echo "ok";
            }
```

Estoy probando solamente. Sin embargo si el usuario introduce {{{{{|{|´|´* o cualquier otro caracter ingresa como válido. como me asugro que solo tenga letras. Ojo no estoy hablando de hacerlo desde el html5. Solo quiero hacerlo desde el backend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No necesitas regex para verificar si un string tiene **solo letras**, puedes usar alguna de las funciones nativas `ctype_*`. Para este caso, [ctype_alpha()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ctype-alpha.php).

```
<?php
var_dump(ctype_alpha('PalabrasMas')); // true
var_dump(ctype_alpha('Palabras Mas')); // false
var_dump(ctype_alpha('U4634f')); // false
```

Más sobre [Funciones C_type](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ref.ctype.php)

Answer (score 0):

La expresión regular sólo está evaluando si contiene algún número. Por lo que los caracteres especiales no hacen match. Podrías probar con [a-zA-Z]{1,}$ dejándolo en el if de siguiente forma:

`if ( empty(trim($nombre)) || !is_string($nombre)  ||  !(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]{1,}$/",$nombre)) ){`

PS: No he podido comprobar el código porque no puedo probar el PHP en esta máquina. Espero que te ayude.

Comment: En esta página puedes probar código PHP http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/